# Finding a string between two lines in a file using linux commands

Tags: linux, grep

I have a file, file.txt, like this:

```
start cal
end cal
start eff
end eff
start cal
error
end cal
start dod
end dod
```

What I want to get is the line between the last set of 'start cal' and 'end cal'.  I am using tac and grep to do it. But in vain.  Any help please?
Below is my code:

```
tac file.txt | grep -m1 'start cal*end cal'
```

What am I doing wrong?  For the example above, I need the command to return 'error'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grep is not good tool for this task. It does line based matching. You can consider using awk.

if you have single line in between:

```
tac file|awk '/end cal/{p=1;next}/start cal/{exit}p'
```

If it could be multiple lines:

```
tac file|awk '/end cal/{p=1;next}/start cal/{exit}p'|tac
```

It outputs:

```
error
```

Comment: Beat me by 13 seconds!  What's that `/pattern/ { commands } variable` syntax?  I don't recognize it.

Comment: I don't understand your question. sorry.. :-( @nephtes

Comment: Oh, never mind, I misread.  It's a condition for the default rule.  Avoids the "if (echo) print" in my solution.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if grep can do it, but here it is in gawk.  I'll be the first to admit, it's not exactly pretty.

```
tac file.txt | gawk '/start cal/ { exit } { if (echo) print } /end cal/ { echo = 1 }'
```

n.b. Kent's answer is better polished.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing two things wrong:

1. grep examines each line separately, so a pattern can never match across two or more lines
2. the regex `start cal*end cal` matches `start ca`, followed by 0 or more `l`s, followed by `end cal`